# Не получаю события VkBotEventType из бесед помимо VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, события

Каким образом можно получить остальные события сообщений (к примеру MESSAGE_REPLY, MESSAGE_EDIT, MESSAGE_EVENT, MESSAGE_TYPING_STATE) из бесед, в которых состоит бот (плюсом ему даны право к доступу ко всей переписке)? Получаю только VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW, хотя в личных сообщениях бота получаю и остальные события (описанные ранее). Просмотрел документацию данную вк - ответа не нашел, просмотрел документацию самой питоновской библиотеки - точно также.
Можно ли вообще с бесед получать подобные события или же они только для личных сообщений сообщества?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю поможет ли это, но вот ссылка на [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs?f=1.2.%20%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B). В ней есть такая пометка:

> Важное замечание: для получения событий из беседы версия API у callback-сервера должна быть не ниже 5.80.